# Necesito obtener un title que esta en un input. PYTHON web scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7

Necesito obtener lo que dice en la etiqueta title que se encuentra en un input:

```
    <div class="control-group" id="ApellidoDiv">

    <label class="control-label" for="apellidos">Apellido<span 
    class="requiredMarkApellidos"><font color="#BD4247">*</font></span></label>

    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" 
   value="" class="input-large nombre success" required="" maxlength="50" 
      title="BLANCO SERRANO" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1">

                    </div>

                </div>
```

y Utilizo html-parser no se como obtenerlo no tengo experiencia con beautifulsoup
Cabe destacar que data es el sitio al cual le deseo hacer scraping.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
inputTag = soup.find(attrs={"id" : "apellidos"})
output = inputTag['title']
```

Sale el siguiente error:

```
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'title'
```

Por favor si me ayudan a obtener ese nombre estaria agradecido.

Comment: Supongo que será en realidad `title="BLANCO SERRANO"` ¿No?  ¿Usas Beautiful Soup con html-parser? ¿Has intentado algo?¿Cual es el problema que se te presenta? Añade la información anterior a la pregunta, en principio bastaría con usar `find` y buscar un tag `input` con `name` o `id` "apellidos".

Comment: Si utilizo html-parser

Comment: @FJSevilla espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: Tu código es correcto siempre y cuando la `id` "apellidos" sea única en todo el html (en realidad que no exista otra etiqueta con esa `id` antes de este `input`). Probablemente estés capturando un elemento que tiene la misma id pero no tiene atributo `title`. Seria bueno si pudieras colocar el html desde el principio del documento hasta este `div` que contiene el input a capturar para ver como podemos hacer la búsqueda más específica.

Comment: hay coloque donde inicia

Comment: Diego si especificas el tag y los atributos un poco más, por ejemplo con `inputTag = soup.find("input", {"type":"text",
                            "name":"apellidos",
                            "id": "apellidos",
                            "class":"input-large nombre success"})` ¿Obtienes el mismo error?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' me sale esto. el sitiio web la url la obtengo despues de llenar una busqueda, creo que toca esperar cierto tiempo para hacer el scraping pero yo obtengo la informacion despues de realizar el submit

Comment: Me di de cuenta que la pagina hace 2 cargues uno del sitio y otro donde le asigna los valores a cada input por eso me retorna vacio.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69255/discussion-between-diego-lopez-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de accesar a los keys es la siguiente

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
inputTag = soup.find(attrs={"id" : "apellidos"})
inputTag['title']
```

ya que la misma variable guarda un diccionario con los elementos html